# Background color for dropdowns doesn't work in IE. jQuery selectors not correct?

Tags: javascript, jquery, drop-down-menu

I have these dropdown menus:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.InterviewSchedules[location.InterviewDates.IndexOf(date)].ChairId, new SelectList(ChairList, "InterviewerId", "FullDetails"), new {@class = "ddlInterviewer" })

@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.InterviewSchedules[location.InterviewDates.IndexOf(date)].CofacilitatorId, new SelectList(NonChairList, "InterviewerId", "FullDetails"), new { @class = "ddlInterviewer" })
```

And this jQuery for changing the background-colors of the dropdown menus. This doesn't work in IE but does in chrome and firefox.

```
$(function () { // SET functions on document ready

    $("#InterviewManagementFrm select").change(function () {
        var text = $('option:selected', $(this)).text();
        var lastChar = text.charAt(text.length - 1)
        if (lastChar == 'A') {
            $(this).removeClass("PreferredPreference");
            $(this).addClass("AcceptedPreference");
        }
        else if (lastChar == 'P') {
            $(this).removeClass("AcceptedPreference");
            $(this).addClass("PreferredPreference");
        }
    });

    $("#InterviewManagementFrm select").each(function () {
        var text = $(this).text();
        var lastChar = text.charAt(text.length - 2)
        if (lastChar == 'A') {
            $(this).addClass("AcceptedPreference");
        }
        else if (lastChar == 'P') {
            $(this).addClass("PreferredPreference");
        }
    });


    $("#InterviewManagementFrm option").each(function () {
        var lastChar = this.text.substr(this.text.length - 1);
        if (lastChar == 'A') {
            if ($(this).is(':selected')) {
                $(this).addClass("AcceptedPreference");
            } else {
                $(this).addClass("AcceptedPreference");
            }
        }
        else if (lastChar == 'P') {


   if ($(this).is(':selected')) {
            $(this).addClass("PreferredPreference");
        } else {
            $(this).addClass("PreferredPreference");
        }
    }
});
}
```

Here is a screenshot of the html:

[image]

[image: IE code inspector]

Could someone help me?

Comment: Perhaps you should accept answers to previous question and then post more

Comment: @Huangism I've accepted your answer. It's more or less what I wanted but I wrote a bit more for the select without the options so everything is differnet color.

Comment: Are the class added correctly in IE? If so then this is more of a css issue then jquery. I am also not 100% sure if background color work well on select/option

Comment: Which IE are you using, http://jsfiddle.net/StdEL/ I see the colors in IE 11 but I am not sure if this works on older IE's

Comment: @Huangism I am using IE10 and below. I think my jQuery selector has to be rewritten for it to work in IE. You see yesterday when I had IDs that were duplicating for each ddl. I removed it because it's bad practise but that's when it was working in IE.

Comment: Did you look at the fiddle in my comment and does it work? Also your js is all messed up, the if is selected statements on your options are basically useless since you are adding the same class either way

Comment: Can you attach a screenshot of an inspect in IE?

Comment: I've added a screenshot with the IE inspector.

Comment: Comparing the 2 screenshots, `AcceptedPreference` class is not on the IE one

Comment: @Huangism Yeah it's because my jQuery works with chrome and firefox but not with IE. My question is for suggestions on how to improve the jQuery and make it work in all three browsers.

Comment: As far as IE10 is concerned, jquery is crossbrowser between the 3 in question. I would suggest you try it out by adding one of your classes without any conditions so it is there for sure and see if it gets added. Or alert what lastchar is to see if it is what you think it is on IE10

Comment: You can try http://jsfiddle.net/StdEL/1/ on IE10, this is just a simple addClass and should work on ie10

Answer (score 0):

there are a lot of limitations as to what you can do with native drop down list in IE.
you will likely want to use some alternative that looks like a drop down list. there are a tone of really nice js dropdowns out there.

once you settle on one, you could write your own template for MVC.

good luck!

dear IE, why do you do su[k so much :(

my solution was to add a message across the top of all my sites that explains to users why they need something else with links to chrome and FF ;)

Comment: IE is the bane of my existence :(. It was actually working when the Dropdowns had an ID but they all had the same ID which is not great so I removed it.

Comment: by dropdown having an id you mean the options or the drop down itself?

Comment: the dropdown itself had an id. It was a HTML attribute for the DropDownFor.

Comment: ID or class it should both ways as long as the class/ID is correct, your jquery adds the same class for selected or not on the options, is that what you wanted or a mistake?

Comment: @Huangism, i was asking because the selector is ID based, though maybe he removed the id forgot to update the selector for the jQuery